# Doubt in rewriting of equation to approximate expectation w.r.t posterior

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm reading Speagle's [A conceptual introduction to Markov Chain Monte Carlo Methds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.12313) to try to learn the contexts where MCMC sampling is needed (in this case the paper focuses on Bayesian inference).

We have the goal of approximating the integral:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{P}}[f(\Theta)]=\int f(\Theta)\mathcal{P}(\Theta)d\Theta
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where:
$$
\mathcal{P}(\Theta)=\frac{\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)}{\int \tilde{\mathcal{P}} \,d\Theta}.
$$
with $\mathcal{P}(\Theta)$ being the posterior, $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)=\mathcal{L}(\Theta)\pi(\Theta)$ being the unnnormalized posterior, $\mathcal{L}(\Theta)$ the likelihood and $\pi(\Theta)$ the prior. We assume that we only know $\mathcal{P}(\Theta)$ up to multiplicative constant, $\propto \mathcal{P}(\Theta)$.

The author proposes to use numerical integration as a first approach, defining a discrete grid and approximating $(1)$ as:

\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{P}}[f(\Theta)]= \frac{\int f(\Theta)\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)d\Theta}{\int \tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)d\Theta}\approx\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f(\Theta_i)\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta_i)\Delta\Theta_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta_i)\Delta\Theta_i}\equiv \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i f_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i},
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $\Theta_i = (\Theta_{j+1}+\Theta_j)/2$ and $\Delta\Theta_i = \Theta_{j+1}-\Theta_j$, for $j=1, \dots, n+1$, and where:
$$
f_i =f(\Theta_i), \qquad w_i = \tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta_i)\Delta \Theta_i.
$$
We thus can consider $(2)$ as a weighted mean. After pointing the flaws of numerical integration, the author introduces a Monte Carlo approach. In order to improve the approximation, we wante to change the grid to make the weights $w_i = \tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta_i)\Delta \Theta_i$ as uniform as possible, so we take
$\Delta \Theta_i \propto 1/\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta_i)$. Taking $n\to \infty$, we can see $\Delta\Theta$ as a function of $\Theta$, $\Delta\Theta(\Theta)$. Using this, we can now define the density of points $\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)$ as:
$$
\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)\propto \frac{1}{\Delta\Theta(\Theta)}.
$$
Quoting the author:

> Using $\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)$, we can now rewrite our original expectation as:
> \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{P}}[f(\Theta)]=\frac{\int f(\Theta)\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)d\Theta}{\int \tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)d\Theta}
>     =\frac{\int f(\Theta)\frac{\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)}{\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)}\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)d\Theta}{\int \frac{\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)}{\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)}\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)d\Theta}=\frac{\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}} \big[f(\Theta)\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)/\mathcal{Q}(\Theta) \big]}{\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}} \big[\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)/\mathcal{Q}(\Theta) \big]}
> \tag{3}
> \end{equation}
> [...]
> Initially, we looked at trying to estimate $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{P}}[f(\Theta)]$
> over a grid with n points. In the limit of infinite resolution, however, our grid becomes
> equivalent to some distribution $\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)$. Using
> $\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)$, we can then rewrite our original expression in terms of two expectations, ${\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}} \big[f(\Theta)\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)/\mathcal{Q}(\Theta) \big]}$ and ${\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{Q}} \big[\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(\Theta)/\mathcal{Q}(\Theta) \big]}$, over
> $\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)$ instead of $\mathcal{P}(\Theta)$. This helps us because we can in theory estimate these final expressions explicitly using a series of n randomly generated samples from $\mathcal{Q}(\Theta)$.

I have two questions.

How exactly is the distribution $\mathcal{Q}$ derived and what does it represent?

I can't get to see the reason for rewriting the expectation and then sampling from $\mathcal{Q}$ to approximate $(1)$ via the last term in $(3)$. Can we not just sample from the distribution $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}$ (which I assume is readily available since it appears in $(3)$ anyway) to approximate $(1)$ using the second term in $(2)$?